# Don't go into this loop if the array is empty

Tags: vba, excel

Til now the method I use to avoid going into for loops which loop through an array which is currently empty is the following:

if len(join(array,"") > 0 then
   for i = 1 to ubound(array)
       code
   next
end if

But this is no joke, I just recently used that line of code if len(join(array,"") > 0 then and that caused the deletion of array and it crashed my program 5 times in a row. I know that sounds hard to believe but here is a screen shot[image]

for some reason the code len(join(array,"") > 0 would destroy the variables2 array.  And here is a screen shot that shows that the variables array is clearly full before I go to the bad code:[image]  So now I'm trying to use a different code I tried:

if not isempty(array) then

But that's not working.  Any ideas?

```
If Len(Join(greek_act, "")) > 0 Then
        For i = 1 To UBound(greek_act)
            For j = 1 To UBound(variables2)
                If greek_act(i) = variables2(j) Then
                variables2(j) = ""
                Exit For
                End If
            Next
        Next
    variables2 = remove_blanks(variables2)
    End If

    'variables2 array is full

    If Len(Join(greek_letters, "")) > 0 Then

    'variables2 array gets destroyed and program crashes here.

            For i = 1 To UBound(greek_letters)
                rightres1 = Replace(rightres1, greek_letters(i), variables2(i))
            Next

    End If
```

Comment: probably need if ubound(array) > 0 combined with a check for nothing  if array is nothing ...

Comment: no, ubound(array) > 0 won't work, because if the array is empty then I get an error message.

Comment: could you please post a code snippet? (don't post your full code, only the relevant part; see [How to create a Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve))

Comment: @user147178  Thats why I stated you need to check for nothing.  First check to see if the array is nothing. if not then check the size of the array.

Comment: Hacky solution, but you can use an 'on error resume next' line to bypass the 'if ubound(array)...' segment then reset the error handling to wtv it was before.

Comment: I did that with the screen shots but I'll do it again.

Comment: I edited the post because someone wnated to see more code.

Comment: @Alter, on error resume next, thanks, I forgot about that.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I decided to just go ahead with the following solution since it appears that the program is temporarily acting up

```
On Error Resume Next

        For i = 1 To UBound(greek_letters)
            rightres1 = Replace(rightres1, greek_letters(i), variables2(i))
        Next



On Error GoTo 0``
```

Answer (score 0):

For the **Join()** technique to work reliably, you must complete the **Dimming/ReDimming** process:

```
Sub dural()
    Dim greek_ary(1 To 3) As String
    s = Join(greek_ary, "")
    MsgBox Len(s)
End Sub
```

Without filling the array, the *Len* will report **0**

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a common test I like to use a reusable function like this:

```
Function IsArrayEmpty(anArray As Variant)
    Dim i As Integer

    On Error Resume Next
        i = UBound(anArray, 1)
    If Err.Number = 0 Then
        IsVarArrayEmpty = False
    Else
        IsVarArrayEmpty = True
    End If
End Function
```

Now in your main Sub do this:

```
If Not IsArrayEmpty(greek_act) Then
    For i = 1 To UBound(greek_act)
        For j = 1 To UBound(variables2)
            If greek_act(i) = variables2(j) Then
                variables2(j) = ""
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
    Next
    variables2 = remove_blanks(variables2)
End If
```